# (mat-snackbar) Accessibility Issue : Field input error is not announced in full

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

snackbar accessibility issue

[image]

I am getting the above accessibility issue in my code but the div which is causing this accessibility issue is not present in my code and its brought by Angular Material.
Similar issue was found on Angular material documentation when I ran the **site improve tool** on **mat-snackbar.**

I am not getting how to resolve the above issue and did not found any solution for that.
Can you please provide the solution to resolve this?